# Android Navigation Component + ViewModel how to keep RecyclerView scroll position when returning from Fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-mvvm

I have the following GamesGridFragment which simply contains a RecyclerView with some Games retrieved from the database in the ViewModel and the games are simply rendered into the adapter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = BottomSheetGamesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    gamesViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GamesViewModel.class);

    gamesViewModel.getGameItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<GameItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<GameItem> gameItems) {
            gamesAdapter.refreshAdapter(gameItems);
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

The refresh adapter method simply clears the old list of elements and then add All again calling notifyItemRangeChanged :

```
public void refreshAdapter(List<GameItem> elements) {
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, displayedElements.size());
    this.displayedElements.clear();
    this.displayedElements.addAll(elements);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, displayedElements.size());
}
```

When a game is selected we simply navigate to the GameDetailFragment.

However, when we navigateUp to the GridFragment, the onCreateView is triggered again and the view resets again (however, the ViewModel ISN'T generated from scratch and retains the last data).

How can I solve this problem and keep the RecyclerView in it's original state when returning from the DetailsFragment without using tricks?